# z3python multiple pow conditional addition

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm working with z3 and I'm coming across the following problem, I want to output a result depending on the current tested value.

For example :

```py
from z3 import *
# This returns a statement
def arrayF(y):
    return If(y % 8 == 7, 255, If(y % 8 == 6, 127, If(y % 8 == 5, 63, If(y % 8 == 4, 31, If(y % 8 == 3, 15, If(y % 8 == 2, 7, If(y % 8 == 1, 3, If(y % 8 == 0, 1, 0))))))))

KEY_LEN = 16
solver = Solver()
pbInput = [BitVec("{}".format(i), 8) for i in range(KEY_LEN)]
for i in range(KEY_LEN):
    solver.add(ascii_printable(pbInput[i]))
# 255 value is taken randomly, not sure there is a solution, this is not the poblem
solver.add(((0x11 &  arrayF(pbInput[1])) << (8 - (pbInput[1] % 8))) + (0x11 + pbInput[1]) == 255)
```

This gives the following traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solve.py", line 12, in <module>
    solver.add(((0x11 &  arrayF(pbInput[1])) << (8 - (pbInput[1] % 8))) + (0x11 + pbInput[1]))  == 255
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'instance'
```

Which is of course because I'm not returning a value out of my function. My question is : how could I manage to return a value from my function, depending on the input instance value?

This is what the big return is suppose to return

```
def arrayF(y):
   z = 0
   for i in range(y):  # not possible as y in an instance, not an int
        z += pow(2, y)
   return z
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to post code segments that people can try on their own to see what's going on! Impossible to decipher what you're really after.

Having said that, the problem is with your modeling of `range(y)`. You can't compute the range on a symbolic value, for obvious reasons. Is `y` an 8-bit value? If that's the case, then you only have 256 inputs; so I'd recommend building a look-up table and simply looking it up. I'd do that even if it's up-to 16-bits or so; anything bigger is probably not practical. But please post MVCE's when asking questions, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I completed my post.